# Why isn't my CodeDeploy to a lambda working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, but a standard serverless .NET core Web API project. I published it to a lambda just fine from Visual Studio with the CloudFormation stack, etc. It all works.

So moving along, I checked it into CodeCommit. That all works. Added a `buildspec.yml` and set it up in CodeBuild. That all works. The project builds fine.

Now I'm trying to setup CodeDeploy... can't for the life of me get this working. I added this `appspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - myStack-AspNetCoreFunction-1HPKU...6GFW:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Name: "myStack-AspNetCoreFunction-1HPKU...6GFW"
        Alias: "AWSServerless1"
        CurrentVersion: "1"
        TargetVersion: "2"
```

I keep getting a CodeDeploy error about the function name and/or alias not being found. I'm not sure what else to put in there?

Any ideas what's wrong? My current error is:

> The deployment failed because either the target Lambda function myStack-AspNetCoreFunction-1HPKU...6GFW does not exist or the specified function version or alias cannot be found

The screen is also showing BeforeAllowTraffic succeeded, but AllowTraffic failed.

Answer (score 0):

does your IAM role you have with your CodeDeploy have the correct IAM allow to deploy Lambda?

Are you running the correct Lambda API call to update or create the Lambda?

Comment: The deployment group is using CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce. The service role ARN is arn:aws:iam::#######:role/CodeDeployServiceRole. Permissions are AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess and AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda. Trusted Entities is codedeploy.amazonaws.com. Do I need to set anything else?

Comment: I just added AWSLambdaFullAccess to the CodeDeployServiceRole and same error.